# Issues laying out custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've created a `UITableView` with a custom `UITableViewCell` from a NIB. On loading the view controller, everything seems to work fine. But when I start to scroll the `UITableView`, there are cases where an empty cell appears in the middle for no reason atall.

I dont know what's happening. My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is quite straightforward. But I've added gestures to the custom `UITableViewCell`. Could that be causing a problem? 
Here my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"FTStreamCell";
    FTStreamCell *cell = (FTStreamCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FTStreamCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        cell.delegate = self;
        return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FTStreamCell *streamCell = (FTStreamCell*) cell;
    if (!indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        if ((NSNull*)[[[self.cachedData objectForKey:kQuestions] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:kQuestion] != [NSNull null])
            streamCell.question.text = [[[self.cachedData objectForKey:kQuestions] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:kQuestion];
        streamCell.timePosted.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Today at Bangalore, India"];
        // To Show My Questions
        NSLog(@"Me %d", [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kUserId] integerValue]);
        if ([[[self.cachedData objectForKey:kQuestions] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:kUserId] == [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kUserId])
        {
            streamCell.mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:244.0f/255.0f green:240.0f/255.0f blue:247.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
            streamCell.userCheck = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            streamCell.mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
            streamCell.userCheck = NO;
        }
        [cell layoutSubviews];
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: enable NSZombie in Xcode so you can know where its crashing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode

Comment: It doenst give me any crash. But the blank cell is still there. I dont have enough reputation to post a screenshot. Here's the link to it. http://i.stack.imgur.com/AgWfw.png

Comment: set breakpoints to to check when is the blank cell loaded. Is it blank because you are using white color in the `else` section?

Comment: i think its crashing becoz you try to access any null object and that why cell being blank. try crashing the app after enabling NSZombie mode than post screen shot here where you got crash.

Comment: I havent set it to white anywhere. I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. Since I dont know exactly when it happens, using breakpoints is a lil hard. Keeps happening on random cells while scrolling.

Comment: I'm not able to crash the app. That's the issue. Even after enabling NSZombie mode.

Comment: That's odd. I enabled NSZombie. I cant seem to reproduce it on my device. But continues to happen on the simulator.

Comment: i think your dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is the problem

Answer (score 0):

UITableViews reuse table cells to reduce memory allocation. So when you begin to scroll the 'white cell' is likely a cell that was previously used and modified before. In the willDisplayCell method try 'resetting' the cell before applying your stylistic changes. The 'reset' will be a custom method of yours that changes everything back to their defaults within the cell.

Comment: how do I do that? Will assigning it to nil or something help?

Comment: You can assign it to nil in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method to force the issue yes. Is there ever a case where section != 0 by the way?

Comment: I have a section with clearColor to show an image behind the tableView. Rest of it is in section 1. Something similar to Path.